# Is there any actual written dialog for the astromech droids?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, r2-d2, bb-8

When R2-D2 and BB-8 converse in *The Force Awakens* for example, is there any written record of what the two characters were saying to each other?

I mean actual dialog, if it exists, and not something like *”BB-8 beeps excitedly”*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. In the script it's all "*BB-8 Beeps excitedly*" and "*BB-8 Bleeps mournfully*", and so on. As far as his '*conversation*' with R2-D2 is concerned, this is what you get:

> LOW WITH BB-8 as he rolls over and finds, under a dark and dusty tarp
>   in a corner, R2-D2. BB-8 BEEPS at R2, pulls off the tarp and tries to
>   start a conversation. But R2 DOESN'T RESPOND AT ALL. BB-8 tries again.
>   Nothing. BB-8 NUDGES R2. Nothing.

...

> As BB-8 approaches R2-D2, the long dormant droid suddenly stirs. The
>   droids beep at each other.

Comment: Those beeps are just masking profanities, anyway.

Comment: @DeerHunter - The novelisation suggests otherwise.

Comment: I prefer DeerHunter's version of reality

Comment: @Richard - Youtube says they are profanities. Since Youtube is owned by Google, and Google runs the world, it ought to be canon

Comment: Just FYI, in the novelisation of 'Revenge of the Sith', there's some dialogue elements for the conversation between R2-D2 and C-3PO; *“I’ve been hearing the most awful rumors-they’re saying the government is going to banish us-banish droids, can you imagine?” DON’T BELIEVE EVERYTHING YOU HEAR.*